# Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token regarding quotation marks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why is it giving this error when i surround the key with quotation marks?:

```
data[0].push({ "col" + (i+1): results.data[i].id});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using brackets ([computed property name from ES6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions#Computed_property_names)):

```
data[0].push({ ["col" + (i+1)]: results.data[i].id});
```

EDIT: If you are able to use ES6, you can also use template literal, as suggested by Ismael:

```
data[0].push({ [`col${i+1}`]: results.data[i].id});
```

Comment: If it is to use ES6, why not ``{ `col${i + 1}`: ... }``? And I'm almost sure that this works in any version of JavaScript.

Comment: Yes, with template literal, it still better. Nice suggestion